# Add a column with the value of the object with max frequency

Tags: r, matrix, max, subset, frequency

I have this matrix:

```
mat=matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,
             4,4,4,4,4,3,5,6,
             3,3,5,5,6,8,0,9,
             1,1,1,1,1,4,5,6),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)
print(mat)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    4
[2,]    4    4    4    4    4    3    5    6
[3,]    3    3    5    5    6    8    0    9
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    4    5    6
```

and a subset with the index of the row I want to apply my function:

```
subset=c(2,4)
```

I would like to add a new column in the matrix "mat" which contains, only for the subset I specified, the value of the object with the max frequency in the row.

In this case:

- for row number 1, I would like to have an empty cell in the new column,
- for row number 2, I would like to have the value "4" in the new column,
- for row number 3, I would like to have an empty cell in the new column,
- for row number 4, I would like to have the value "1" in the new column.

EDIT:
thanks for the code in the answer!
now i should replace the NA values with other values: 
i have another matrix:

`mat2=matrix(c(24,1,3,2, 4,4,4,4, 3,2,2,5, 1,3,5,1),nrow=4,byrow=TRUE)`

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   24    1    3    2
[2,]    4    4    4    4
[3,]    3    2    2    5
[4,]    1    3    5    1
```

and the subset:

```
subset=c(1,3)
```

i want to replcace the `NA` of the matrix (the remaining rows out of the first subeset) with the colnames of the value of the row with the max value.

in this case, i will have "1" for the first row and "4" for the third one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are looking for the mode. Unfortunately R doesn't provide a builtin mode function. But it is not too hard to write your own one:

```
## create mode function
modeValue <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}

## add new column with NA
smat <- cbind(mat, NA)

## calculate mode for subset
smat[subset, ncol(smat)] <- apply(smat[subset, , drop=FALSE], 1, modeValue)
smat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
# [1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    4   NA
# [2,]    4    4    4    4    4    3    5    6    4
# [3,]    3    3    5    5    6    8    0    9   NA
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    4    5    6    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will work. It calculates such values (modes)for all rows then substitutes missings where desired:

```
myFunc <- function(x, myRows) {

  myModes <- apply(mat, 1, FUN=function(i) {
                temp<- table(i)
                as.numeric(names(temp)[which.max(temp)])
             })
  myModes[setdiff(seq.int(nrow(x)), myRows)] <- NA
  myModes
}
```

For the example, this returns

```
myFunc(mat, c(2,4))
[1] NA  4 NA  1
```

To add this to your matrix, just use `cbind`:

```
cbind(mat, myFunc(mat, c(2,4)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    4   NA
[2,]    4    4    4    4    4    3    5    6    4
[3,]    3    3    5    5    6    8    0    9   NA
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    4    5    6    1
```